# How to populate a ComboBox with a string array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

```
Private Sub frmQuery3_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    frmQuery2.Hide()
    Dim columns As String = frmQuery2.GetColumns
    cmbColumnSort.MaxDropDownItems = columns.Length
    For stepper = 0 To (columns.Length - 1)
        cmbColumnSort.Items.Add(columns(stepper))
    Next
End Sub
```

cmbColumnSort is initially an empty ComboBox. What I would like to do is fill the ComboBox with the string array columns, which shouldn't empty(it certainly isn't in frmQuery2).

The thing is, it doesn't work. I've tried a Step Into to see whether the property GetColumns actually returns a filled array(as the array in frmQuery2 is filled), but the Step Into just skips from the third line of the above code and loads the form, awaiting further input, and leaving the ComboBox empty. Help?

Comment: Use the debugger to see if you get an exception.

Comment: Put your code inside of `try catch`.

Comment: The thing is that the code compiles, but the combobox doesn't get populated... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a string array to get columns, so use `Dim columns() As String`

The below code is working fine

```
    Dim columns() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}
    ComboBox1.MaxDropDownItems = columns.Length
    For stepper = 0 To (columns.Length - 1)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(columns(stepper))
    Next
```

I suggest you make  your code clearer and easier to write using `For Each`

```
    Dim columns() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}
    ComboBox1.MaxDropDownItems = columns.Length
    For Each column As String In columns
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(column)
    Next
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't want to create array

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(columns)
```